# How do you pass optional boolean arguments in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to display a welcome message on the Dashboard to the user when he can from the welcome page.
So, in my route for the Dashboard, I defined a optional argument.

It's working fine to access it without any argument (because, it's optional) but when I add one, it's not working anymore.

```kotlin
       composable(Routes.welcome) {
            WelcomeScreen {
                navController.navigate("dashboard?isWelcome={true}")
            }
        }

        composable(
            "dashboard?isWelcome={isWelcome}}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("isWelcome") {
                    type = NavType.BoolType
                }
            )
        ) {
            val isFromWelcome = it.arguments?.getBoolean("isWelcome") ?: false
...
}
```

The error I have :

```
Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/dashboard?isWelcome={true} } cannot be found in the navigation graph
```

Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: It's `navController.navigate("dashboard?isWelcome=true` not `navController.navigate("dashboard?isWelcome={true}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sending boolean

```
val booleanValue = true
navController.navigate("my_destination?my_arg_id=${booleanValue}")
```

### Receiving boolean

```
composable(
    route = "my_destination?my_arg_id={my_arg_id}",
    arguments = listOf(navArgument("my_arg_id") { defaultValue = false })
) { from ->
    val myBooleanArg = from.arguments?.getBoolean("my_arg_id")
    MySecondScreen(myBooleanArg)
}
```

Comment: route is wrong. You will always receive false with this. According to official doc (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#optional-args) you have to put `{ }` in route. For example: `route = "my_destination?my_arg_id={$booleanValue}",`